Python - Attribute Lookup without triggering `__getattribute__`?
How on earth do you SAFELY lookup an attribute, without triggering either the class OR the metaclass's __getattribute__ method?
object.__getattribute__, a function I believed to be totally safe, is raising an AttributeError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\tricks.py", line 49, in update_class_instances
    if isinstance(obj, old_class):
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\system\path.py", line 104, in __instancecheck__
    return cls.__subclasscheck__(instance.__class__)
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\system\path.py", line 107, in __subclasscheck__
    return pathlib_to_override(cls) in pathlib_to_override(subclass).__mro__
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\logger_util.py", line 471, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(instance, attr_name)
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\logger_util.py", line 524, in __getattribute__
    if isinstance(e, AttributeError) and object.__getattribute__(self, "__getattr__") is not None:
AttributeError: 'ExampleClass' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

So naturally I then tried type.__getattribute__. Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\tricks.py", line 83, in debug_reload_pymodules
    update_class_instances(old_attribute, new_attribute)
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\tricks.py", line 52, in update_class_instances
    RobustRootLogger.exception(f"Error updating class '{old_class.__class__.__name__}'")
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\logger_util.py", line 471, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(instance, attr_name)
  File "C:\GitHub\PyKotor\Libraries\Utility\src\utility\logger_util.py", line 524, in __getattribute__
    if isinstance(e, AttributeError) and type.__getattribute__(our_type, "__getattr__") is not None:
AttributeError: type object 'ExampleClass' has no attribute '__getattr__'

Related links:
Python: Can a class forbid clients setting new attributes?
Python 3 - Check class attribute without calling __getattr__
Is there a 100% safe way to lookup attributes on a python object and/or type, without wrapping in a try-catch? Thank you for taking the time to read my newbie question!
Note The code I'm writing is diving deep into the internals of Python, and due to its nature is bound to cause weird random issues such as this (i'm experimenting with importlib, __import__, and sys.modules. Since it is not related to the question I'm not going to clutter the thread with that code.

what do you mean by SAFELY?   "object.__getattribute__, a function I believed to be totally safe, is raising an AttributeError:" so what? that's what it is supposed to do when there is no attribute. That is what I would call safe. Why do you want to not use try-except? You can write a function that uses a try-except, and returns some default value, indeed getattr can do that already if you provide an argument to the default parameter (third positional), or whatever. But it isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish exactly or what the problem you are encountering is.

As in, get an attribute without calling the metaclass's getattribute/getattr and without calling class's getattribute/getattr. Just a simple raw lookup. A metaclass is somewhat bugged and is throwing unreasonable exceptions for calls with object.__getattribute__, I realize the above tracebacks were not the greatest examples.
